# Spring MVC requestMapping: map if either param 1 or 2 is present

Tags: spring, rest, controller

I want to map a GET-request to a controller method if the parameter `"query"` or `"tag"` or both of them exist.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", params = {"query", "tag"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

The problem here is that a list of params requires all of them to exist. I want it to be called when at least one of them is present.

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround to solve this problem:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", params = "query", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void entryFunc1( ... lots of params ...) {
     actualFunc(...);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "", params = "tag", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void entryFunc2( ... lots of params ...) {
     actualFunc(...);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "", params = {"query", "tag"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void entryFunc3( ... lots of params ...) {
     actualFunc(...);
}

private void actualFunc( ... lots of params ...) {
     ... do actual work ...
}
```

This is a LOT of duplicate code. Note that the third entry function is also needed because otherwise, if both parameters are present, I would get an ambiguous handler exception.